# Why is this work formula only applicable for constant forces?

Tags: forces, work, distance

I was told that the following formula works only for a constant force case.

$$W = F\times d \times \cos \theta$$

Why is that?

Comment: Your formula is for a specific case. The correct formula is $dW = \vec{F}.d\vec{x}$

Comment: Could you explain why it only take constant force? What would happen if I used a varying force?

Comment: Your formula won't work if the force is varying. You need to use the general definition and integrate the expression to find the net work done.

Answer (score 4):

The general formula for work done by displacement is:

$$dW = \vec{F}(x) . d\vec{x}$$

$$W_{ab} = \int_a^b \vec{F}(x) . d\vec{x}$$

The formula you showed ($W=Fd\cos\theta$) is a special case of the above formula.

If the force is constant (magnitude as well as direction), the force $\vec{F}$ can be pulled out of the integral along with the dot product.

$$W_{ab} = \int_a^b \vec{F} . d\vec{x} = F \cos \theta \int_a^b d\vec{x} = F \cos \theta \left[x\right]_a^b = F \Delta x \cos \theta$$

The above formula is what your textbook has given you. This formula works only for constant forces and this is because we assumed that the force was constant while deriving it.

Answer (score 0):

Work is the area under the force-distance plot. By force, I mean the component of net forces along the direction of motion.

If this force is constant then $W = F \Delta x$

But if the force is a function of distance (like a spring) then $$ W = \int F(x) \,{\rm d}x$$

WIth an ideal spring $F=-k x$, where $x$ is the displacement from the balanced state. Then, work is $$W  = -k \int x {\rm d}x = -\frac{k}{2} (\Delta x)^2 =\frac{1}{2} F( \Delta x ) \,\Delta x$$